# Expo document picker necesita permisos?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

estoy desarrollando una app que permitirá subir archivos pdf utilziar react native y expo, en mi búsqueda me encontré con que es posible hacer esta tarea más sencilla usando expo-document-picker, expo-image-picker usa expo permissions para pedir permiso de acceder a la galería no obstante no encuentro forma de hacer que expo-document-picker pida permisos y en la documentación no hay nada al respecto ¿Podría ser posible que no sean necesarios?

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación no necesitas pedir permisos para expo-document-picker.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/

En caso de que necesite algún permiso por lo general la librería lo pide automáticamente.